# Cancel/Interrupt a query.execute() on cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've just created an script with a long time query, and I added a signal handled that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it launches a `connection.close()`.

But when I run the py script and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it just waits until the execute has ended to handle the signal.

Is there any way I can cancel it while running?

```
def signal_term_handler(signal, frame):
    connection.cancel()
    sys.exit('Excution stopped manually.')

ip = IP
port = PORT
SID = SID
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(USER, PASS, dsn_tns)
cursor = connection.cursor()


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_term_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_term_handler)
cursor.execute(QUERY)
```

`QUERY` is a query with multiple selects that lasts for around 4 minutes.

Comment: What are the client & DB server platforms?  What Oracle versions?  Are you using a VM? Is your firewall blocking/inlining out of band breaks?  Tried a sqlnet.ora DISABLE_OOB=on parameter?

Comment: Thanks 2 @ChristopherJones. Im using oracle-xe-11 on docker, and the last version of cx_oracle. Where shall I use the slqnet.ora DISABLE_OOB? I've checked the dock and it might be off (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/sqlnet.htm#NETRF185)

Comment: When I test your code and leave out the signal handlers stuff, the connection is cleaned up right after hitting ctrl-C. Why not use regular python exceptions in  a try block?

Comment: @SergioGonzález here is some info on sqlnet.ora files: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#tnsadmin  Although the documentation is for node-oracledb, it applies to cx_Oracle (and many other Oracle client applications)

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
  cursor.execute(QUERY)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  sys.exit('Excution stopped manually.')
```

This should be close to what you want.
It looks like cx_Oracle re-raises the KeyBoardInterrupt so to do a complete catch you need to nest the handler in an extra outer try: except KeyboardInterrupt: